# Display and edit user info

Tags: 7, users

When a user logs in, I'd like him to see his profile info (name, address) with a link to a form to edit that info.
I thought this should be a trivial task, because it is something needed on almost every site that allows users to register. Yet, I failed to get anywhere after a couple of hours of trying and searching.

What I have now is a view (using the views module) that displays a list of all users where each one has a link to the edit page. But I only want a user to see and edit his own stuff ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may put template for user page like  `user-profile.tpl.php`
This template is used when viewing a registered member's profile page,

e.g., example.com/user/123. 123 being the users ID.

Available variables:

`$user_profile`: An array of profile items. Use render() to print them.
Field variables: for each field instance attached to the user a corresponding variable is defined; e.g., $user->field_example has a variable $field_example defined. When needing to access a field's raw values, developers/themers are strongly encouraged to use these variables. Otherwise they will have to explicitly specify the desired field language, e.g. $user->field_example['en'], thus overriding any language negotiation rule that was previously applied.

**OR**

use `hook_menu_link_alter`

```
function hook_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
  // Make all new admin links hidden (a.k.a disabled).
  if (strpos($item['link_path'], 'admin') === 0 && empty($item['mlid'])) {
    $item['hidden'] = 1;
  }
  // Flag a link to be altered by hook_translated_menu_link_alter().
  if ($item['link_path'] == 'devel/cache/clear') {
    $item['options']['alter'] = TRUE;
  }
  // Flag a link to be altered by hook_translated_menu_link_alter(), but only
  // if it is derived from a menu router item; i.e., do not alter a custom
  // menu link pointing to the same path that has been created by a user.
  if ($item['link_path'] == 'user' && $item['module'] == 'system') {
    $item['options']['alter'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil. I had found sth. like this before, but just couldn't believe it was necessary to write php code just to display profile data. I thought it was the whole point of the views module to get around such programming? That hook function thing I don't understand at all (what it's supposed to do, where to put it, how to call it). Would you have a link to documentation?

Comment: See here http://api.lullabot.com/group/menu_example/7

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sure it does, but I still don't see how this relates to the problem. Why would I want to alter a menu link? (The site that I'm working on doesn't even have a menu). Perhaps I'll get back to it in a couple of months after reading a couple more Drupal books ...

Comment: Now I tried to display $user_profile variables. But: $user_profile is NULL (tried in page.tpl.php). I also tried $user, which has content, but nothing useful for me ...

Comment: I think you cleared the cache. If yes try define this tpl through your template.php

Comment: Sure I cleared the cache. Clearing it all the time, otherwise, how would I see what's happening? The template I'm using (stark) has no template.php. I had a look at the bartik theme, but could not see any tpls defined there. So, ahem, I have no idea how to do this ...

Comment: Try define them through any of your modules. Its also possible.

Comment: Sorry, way over my head. No idea how to define anything through a module. Meanwhile I found this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/8385/6519 - "Accessing Additional User Profile Fields". This works, but seems overly complex (access a field: $user_full->field_zip["und"][0]["safe_value"]), and I have yet to figure out a *reasonable* way to output this on a page ...

Comment: You have to do this till you use Drupal. Please post here if you find any other solution. This is the Drupal reasonable  way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Same Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073793/how-to-redirect-a-user-to-his-account-page-after-login

Comment: CP is not asked for "redirect after login". Read before you answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at this module and the redirections link. Only in this case I don't want to send users to another page, but simply display the profile info on a normal basic page, with a link to the account page.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I thought that a redirect to the Profile edit Page would be the solution.